# Why does my Mac have laggy/choppy Dock magnification effect?

Tags: macos, dock, macbook-pro, animation

I have a retina MacBook Pro and I noticed a laggy/choppy magnification effect when hovering the mouse over the dock. I thought Mountain Lion would fix that, but apparently its a bit more laggy now as well.

Is there a fix for this?

Also, the default settings had the magnification effect turned off, does Apple acknowledge they have a laggy dock or what?

*Update*

For some unknown reason, the dock is not choppy today, except on the far right (applications, downloads and Trash) .. I have no explanation to why the other parts of the dock stopped being choppy when magnified.

Comment: My late 2010 MacBook Air (13", 256 MB DDR5 memory graphics, 4 GB RAM) lags as well. Could it be the OS and not the hardware?

Comment: I too see that the scrolling lag hasnt gotten much better with ML.. instead it is worse than it was in lion! I am using the base-model. I would expect a 2k+ computer to be running smoothly.
Unfortunate.

Comment: Well putting the dock on the left or right side of the screen fixes the issue...Im not sure why it lags only when its place in the middle ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, a lot of the graphics on the MacBook Pro with Retina Display are a bit choppy (for example, scrolling and window resizing). The new rMBP simply has **a lot of pixels**, and the graphics card is no better than the one in the regular MBP. In the next few years we can probably expect this to improve with further software optimizations and better hardware offerings.

See also:

- [Retina MacBook Pro Pushes the Limits of its Graphics Capabilities](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/29/retina-macbook-pro-pushes-the-limits-of-its-graphics-capabilities/) (MacRumors)
- [Driving the Retina Display: A Performance Discussion](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6023/the-nextgen-macbook-pro-with-retina-display-review/8) (AnandTech)

Comment: @bmike I think your edit would be better as a comment on the original question :)